# Адаптивный дизайн приложений на Android

Tags: android

А как можно сделать адаптивный дизайн приложений на Android (смартфоны, планшеты), там ведь разные расширения?
И можно это сделать по аналогии с адаптивным дизайном сайтов?

Comment: попробуйте это почитать

http://hashcode.ru/questions/99233/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-7-%D0%B8-android-2-2
но лучше всего на developer.android.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

если я правильно понял то тебя интересует верстка под разные размеры экранов? 
layout файлы и изображения хранят в разных папках

res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density

подробнее  об этом http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html